# ANTLR: Walking through if/elseif/else javascript

Tags: javascript, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I know there is a lot about such a problem but I can't find any solution to my problem. So any help will be much appreciated.

I'm trying to parse js file with ANTLR in java.
I'm using the lexer and parser g4 files from antlr-github

[JavaScriptLexer.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/javascript/JavaScriptLexer.g4)
[JavaScriptParser.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/javascript/JavaScriptParser.g4)

Then I use `JavaScriptListener` for parsing.
The problem I faced is the nested construction of if/else blocks.
For example, I have the following js code:

```
if (if_1) {
    a=b;
    if (nested_if_1) {
        nested_if_a=nested_if_b;
    }
} else if (else_if_1) {
    else_if_1_a = else_if_1_b;
}
```

Here the problem is how to find out the `else if` to which is blocks belong?
Or how can I figure it out that second if it is inside the first one?

As listener has only two methods related to if:

> enterIfStatement(JavaScriptParser.IfStatementContext ctx)
>
> exitIfStatement(JavaScriptParser.IfStatementContext ctx)

**UPDATE**

For the better understanding here is the walker output

The listener entry/exit output for if statement

```
+enterIfStatement: if(if_1){a=b;if(nested_if_1){nested_if_a=nested_if_b;}}elseif(else_if_1){else_if_1_a=else_if_1_b;}
    enterStatement: {a=b;if(nested_if_1){nested_if_a=nested_if_b;}}
        +enterIfStatement: if(nested_if_1){nested_if_a=nested_if_b;}
        -exitIfStatement: if(nested_if_1){nested_if_a=nested_if_b;}
        exitStatement: if(nested_if_1){nested_if_a=nested_if_b;}
    exitStatement: {a=b;if(nested_if_1){nested_if_a=nested_if_b;}}
    enterStatement: if(else_if_1){else_if_1_a=else_if_1_b;}
        +enterIfStatement: if(else_if_1){else_if_1_a=else_if_1_b;}
        -exitIfStatement: if(else_if_1){else_if_1_a=else_if_1_b;}
    exitStatement: if(else_if_1){else_if_1_a=else_if_1_b;}
-exitIfStatement: if(if_1){a=b;if(nested_if_1){nested_if_a=nested_if_b;}}elseif(else_if_1){else_if_1_a=else_if_1_b;}
```

Answer (score 0):

We're considering the following grammar rule respected to grammar:

```
ifStatement
    : If '(' expressionSequence ')' statement (Else statement)?
    ;
```

That's why `ifStatement` listener methods are being called in the following order:

1. enter to `if_1`
2. enter to `nested_if_1`
3. exit from `nested_if_1`
4. enter to `else_if_1`
5. enter from `else_if_1`
6. exit from `if_1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ivan. To be honest I didn't get how can I distinguish which one enters to/from?  I updated question the entry/exit output so you can point out on than output. As it is only if block I have to somehow differentiate 'if' from 'else if'